Welcome text blazor app keeps receiving error "Error. An error occurred while processing your request." I cannot get past this error page
The Welcome text app's purpose is to generate a web link to the WelcomeText site and send the link to a new customer. On the site, the customer is supposed to be greeted by a welcome message, but the welcome page never displays and instead goes immediately to an error page

Development Mode Swapping to the Development environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred

Error being received
The app is being published from Visual Studio to an IIS web server. The last 2 error logs I received when running it were:

An ISAPI reported an unhealthy condition to its worker process. Therefore, the worker process with process id of '924' serving application pool 'WelcomeText' has requested a recycle.

and

Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          11/5/2024 3:27:33 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      BLAZOR.hometowne.local
Description:
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
SpanId: 23bb04c94decbf4d
TraceId: a03b83ddef80d2323a257ad2617d08b3
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 40008782-0006-be00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /welcome/feeeef
ActionId: 6b03fe1e-b4a6-4b60-8b05-a45167a2a608
ActionName: /_Host
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
at WelcomeText.Shared.Pinegrow.UpdateProgressBar(MessageArgs args) in \WelcomeText\Shared\Pinegrow.razor:line 67
at BlazorComponentBus.ComponentBus.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.b__2()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at BlazorComponentBus.ComponentBus.Publish[T](T message, CancellationToken ct)
at WelcomeText.Pages.WelcomePage.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\jkligel\source\repos\hometowne001\HTCApps\WelcomeText\Pages\WelcomePage.razor:line 67
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
at ...

I tried commenting out this line of code:
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

Image of code
and I also tried changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value from "Development" to "Production"
image of launchSettings.json
None of the solutions worked.
My web.config says
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WelcomeText.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 4a5d8fb7-ed18-42d5-a130-e51889d7df34-->


i would like to confirm is your application running locally i mean on visual studio without any issue? which .net version you are using? do you have any custom code used in your application? could just create simple blazor application without any custom code and deploy on iis. and may i know how you are deploying the app? Have you downloaded and installed .net hosting bundle and runtime? What does your web.confifg file contain?

Try to enable detailed error message to see what is the actual issue"Logging": {        "LogLevel": {          "Default": "Warning",          "Microsoft": "Debug",          "System": "Debug"        }      } is it possible for you to share the reproducible sample with us if simple app works

It produces the same error page locally when running the application. The .net version is 8.0. Other apps are deployed on iis without issue. I am deploying the app by publishing it from Visual Studio locally to a virtual server containing iis.

The error is on WelcomeText\Shared\Pinegrow.razor:line 67. And the error message even suggests a way to fix it.

for the error: "System.InvalidOperationException: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state." try to use InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); in the code. if you are still facing issue set the envionmnet to Development temparray to see the detailed error

@JalpaPanchal Adding the InvokeAsync worked. When trying to fix it, I kept putting InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged()) which was not working, but what you stated was what fixed it. Thanks to you and Henk Holterman.


Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The current thread is not
associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution
to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged() at
WelcomeText.Shared.Pinegrow.UpdateProgressBar(MessageArgs args) in
\WelcomeText\Shared\Pinegrow.razor:line 67

For this error you could use the await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()); or InvokeAsync to resolve the issue.
The reason behind the error because of an attempt to update the UI from a non-UI thread in Blazor.
